# Eclipse: The archive which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

My Eclipse is Indigo Java classic.

I have a java project which has mockito-all as a dependency. pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

run `mvn clean install`, everything is ok. Then I did `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to resolve all the dependencies in Eclipse.

when I try to run a Junit in eclipse, it doesn't run and gives me this error:

```
'Launching YourTest' has encountered a problem.

The archive: /home/shengjie/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.9.5.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
```

My project pom.xml claims it's depending on mockito-all 1.8.5, I am not sure where the 1.9.5 reference is coming from. Any ideas?

==EDIT==

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | grep mockito
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test
[INFO] \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.4.12:test
[INFO] \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test (version managed from 1.9.0)
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test (version managed from 1.9.5; scope managed from compile)
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test (version managed from 1.9.5; scope managed from compile)
[INFO] \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.4.12:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test (version managed from 1.9.5; scope managed from compile)
```

Comment: Are you sure your pom.xml does not have another dependency where it depends on version 1.9.5?

Comment: added a mvn dependency:tree dump, Please have a look:)

Comment: Not an answer, but an alternative: is it possible to use m2e in your Eclipse environment?

Comment: Have you tried to remove reference to mockito-all.jar version 1.9.5 manually from your application library?

Comment: @Korhan Öztürk how do you do that?

Comment: Simply from project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries

Comment: @Korhan Öztürk did that at the beginning. only 1.8.5 is there.

Answer (score 88):

I had a similar problem while I was trying to start my tomcat. I would suggest that you check "Classpath" the following way:

1) Run Configurations

- Right click on your project

  - then click "Run" -> "Run Configurations..."
  - there check your settings for you project (e. g. in my case it was the Apache Tomcat)
  - here look into you tab "Classpath" under "User Entries"

2) Project classpath

- Right click on your project -> "Properties" -> "Java Build Path"

  - now check the "Source" Tab as well as your "Libraries" Tab
  - Problems should be marked red in the "Libraries" tab

Comment: The Run Configurations was my problem. Thanks.

Comment: The Run Configurations was also my problem. After I pressed the "Restore Default Entries" button from the Run Configurations -> Classpath tab then the entries under "User Entries" were refreshed.

Comment: *16/05/2019*, this aswer saved me. Thanks Birol!

Comment: YOUR_WORKSPACE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches is where the launch configuration is stored

Answer (score 8):

In my case with using ANT I change the setting in Windows --> Preferences --> Ant --> Runtime --> Global Entries. 
You need to add tools.jar as an External Jar.

Comment: Awesome. I wonder why it suddenly changed though. After an update maybe?

Comment: Worked for me. But still don't understand why this error was happening, as the other libs in the same folder were apparently being found (or maybe not being searched for?). =/

Answer (score 5):

Go to Window > Show View > Navigator

There you will see `.classpath` file where the dependencies related to your **M2 Repo** can be seen

An example would be -

```
<classpathentry 
 exported="true" 
 kind="var" 
 path="M2_REPO/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1-redhat-2/activation-1.1.1-redhat-2.jar"/>
```

Change the version to the one under

> Project Explorer > Your Project > Libraraies >  Maven Dependencies

[image]

Hopefully this will resolve the issue.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a JRE installed then added a JDK. ANT seemed to stick with the JRE even though I changed my project to use the JDK.

To fix this I had to do:
1. Select "Run As..."
2. Select the second "Ant build..." option
3. This brings up a panel to allow setting configuration. Choose the "JRE" tab and change the selected JRE to the JDK

Answer (score 1):

If any of the previous answers didn't work, try this :
Right click on your project -> Debug As -> Open Debug Dialog ... -> In the classpath you'll find the jar causing you the trouble. Remove it.

Hope this work for you as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this problem

[image]

**Resolution :-**

As stated in error "The archive: /AutomationPrj/src/test/resources/**resources** which is referenced by the classpath, **does not exist**."

In my project /AutomationPrj/src/test/resources**/resources**  indeed does not exists. I created resources folder [empty] at appropriate location and issues resolved.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It might be the version issue of java and eclipse.

I upgraded from kepler to mars and I was using JAVA 1.7.
I faced the same issue with tools.jar.

I downgrade the eclipse and this time build ran successfully.
It might help you.