# Corrupt classpath in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I'm getting errors like

The archive: C:/Users/John/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.

Prior to this error, I had the error missing hsqldb-2.0.0 in similar path, and added the jar.

when running programs in a specific project.  Other projects run fine.  How to fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435221/the-archive-which-is-referenced-by-the-classpath-does-not-exist

Comment: did you ran `mvn clean install` and `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and installed `m2eclipse` plugin?

Comment: Thanks LB, I did read that earlier, and went back to it.

In "Run" -> "Run Configurations..." -> "Java Applications" -> Classpath I see the following

M2_REPO/org/... files I'm missing.  

At first I couldn't modify since all buttons are grey, but I was able to click on the project name and select exported entries only, and the entries were removed.